# Eigen Matrix.inverse() crashes when using Intel MKL Libraries

Tags: eigen, intel-mkl

I am using Intel(R) MKL 2018 with Eigen. Calls to matrix multiplications work well. However when I call mat.inverse() it results in a crash. Wondering if anyone has run into this issue

Here is the Code I am using. I am running in VS 2017. The cmd shell closes when I step over "MatrixXd mat3 = mat*mat2;" Which means the call to multiplication does work either. All these code runs fine if I remove the #define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL.

```
#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL      // Use Intel Math Kernel LIbrary for Matrix operations
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/LU"

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{

  MatrixXd mat = MatrixXd::Random(100,100);
  MatrixXd mat2 = mat;

  MatrixXd mat3 = mat*mat2;

  MatrixXd invMat =mat.inverse();

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you do? Provide a [mre]! How does it crash?

Comment: Here is the code that results in the crash. I am using VS 2017. Just updated to MKL 2019.5. Still results in the same crash.#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL      // Use Intel Math Kernel LIbrary for Matrix operations
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/LU"



using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  MatrixXd invMat(4000,4000);
  MatrixXd mat = MatrixXd::Random(100,100);

  invMat=mat.inverse();

}

Comment: Please use the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58661900/edit) link to edit the actual question. Also write how the program crashes.

Comment: @chtz, I am not sure what else to provide. I have updated the original post with  a simple program to reproduce the crash. Please let me know if I can provide anything else. Apologize for any errors. This is my first post in the forum

Comment: I found the issue. Had to select Intel Performance Libraries under Configuration Properties for the #define to work properly